# How to handle keys on certain area

Tags: javascript

I wan to ask you, how to handle keys on certain area with this library http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/ It's shown only with document, and when i try '#dmine_div' it does not work.How it must be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the source for shortcut.js shows that selectors are not supported and the default `document.getElementById(target)` is called. try to pass `'dmine_div'` as the argument for target